# Increasing WebSQL size for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web-sql

I have a web application that uses a lot of offline storage. It was running good until the data increased and reached around 8MB. Whenever storing that much data to the WebSQL, I received error stating "The inspeted target has crashed." I assume that it has to do with the storage capacity, although I am not sure. Since everything was working fine until the data increased, I would like to check after increasing the WebSQL capacity. There is a post I read that talk about creating a manifest.json file. My question is

1. Does this work for web applications?
2. Where is this file placed?
3. What are the furhter steps to take after creating this file?
4. What about other browsers? Does this solve problem for only Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the implementation of your WebSQL. I have offline databases in WebSQL that are well over 100MB and load in Chrome without a hitch.